# how to perform queries on external website

Tags: jquery, coding-style

i am actually looking to perform some search on external website when a button is clicked on my website .i don't have an idea how i can achieve this behaviour with php,javascript or any other language

to better clear my question please look at below url

http://instantdomainsearch.com/

type sfdsdf and click on buy button what it does push the user to godaddy and perform a domain search for him without he have to do anything

```
$(go to url).click()
{perform search on url automatically}
```

Comment: instantdomainsearch site use temporary token to avoid this kind of request. I don't think someone will help you to perform this kind of task, this is clearly against their TOS.

Comment: Is this query specific to Instantdomainsearch? Google is easy to do (see @kdeveloper below, or just Google for instructions), but other sites may not be possible unless they explicitly allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the trick here is to get the url format for the search engine you want to target

for e.g. the url to search in google is http://google.com/#q=*[query string]*

so to search for php you can use the following url :

http://google.com/#q=php

Keeping this in mind you can write a javascript/jquery code to perform accordingly

Comment: How does this help you depends on your exact requirement but still I made a small example for you

Take a look at http://kshah.5gbfree.com/search.php 

Feel free to look at the code

Its pretty easy yet if you encounter any problem you can ask me

Comment: ok thanks that was easy to follow but how about doing the same with sites like godaddy